# Insert in array only when the object with specific id is not present

Tags: javascript

I want to push  objects in an array on when the no object with the is is already present in array.
i tried below, but it gives redundant values (prints all)

```
var array=[
  {id:124, value:"a", name:"e"},
  {id:124, value:"b", name:"f"},
  {id:125, value:"c", name:"g"},
  {id:126, value:"d", name:"h"}
];
var newarray= array.reduce(function (a, b) {
  if (a.indexOf(b.id) == -1) {
    a.push(b)
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(newarray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `indexOf` test doesn't make sense when checking to see whether an array of objects contains a primitive: either use an `.every` check instead, to ensure every item in the accumulator has no matching ID:

```js
var array=[
  {id:124, value:"a", name:"e"},
  {id:124, value:"b", name:"f"},
  {id:125, value:"c", name:"g"},
  {id:126, value:"d", name:"h"}
];
var newarray= array.reduce(function (a, b) {
  if (a.every(item => item.id !== b.id)) {
    a.push(b)
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(newarray);
```

Or, to be a bit more performant, when pushing to the accumulator, also add IDs to an outer variable, perhaps a `Set`:

```js
var array=[
  {id:124, value:"a", name:"e"},
  {id:124, value:"b", name:"f"},
  {id:125, value:"c", name:"g"},
  {id:126, value:"d", name:"h"}
];
var ids = new Set();
var newarray = array.reduce((a, b) => {
  if (!ids.has(b.id)) {
    ids.add(b.id);
    a.push(b);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(newarray);
```

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf` won't work here as you are checking the existance of a string inside an array of objects. You can use `some` or `every` for this like so:

```
var newarray= array.reduce(function (a, b) {
  if (!a.some(function(obj) { return obj.id == b.id; })) == -1) {
    a.push(b)
  }
  return a;
}, []);
```

An alternative solution to `reduce` would be to use `filter`/`findeIndex` combo to remove duplicates:

```
var newarray= array.filter(function (o, i) {
  return array.findIndex(function(obj) {
    obj.id == o.id;
  }) == i;
});
```

Which can be shortened using arrow functions:

```
var newarray= array.filter((o, i) =>
  array.findIndex(obj => obj.id == o.id) == i
);
```

**Example:**

```js
var array= [
  {id:124, value:"a", name:"e"},
  {id:124, value:"b", name:"f"},
  {id:125, value:"c", name:"g"},
  {id:126, value:"d", name:"h"}
];

var newarray= array.filter((o, i) =>
  array.findIndex(obj => obj.id == o.id) == i
);

console.log(newarray);
```

Comment: Thanks .Can i tweak the same if i want to find objects with specific IDS from another array.?
ex:  IDList=[125,126]  and now i want all objects from the array whose ID matches from my IDList?? something like : [
  {id:125, value:"c", name:"g"},
  {id:126, value:"d", name:"h"}
]

Comment: @LearntoCode Simply `map` `IDList`, and for each ID, `find` the object from the array: `let objects = IDList.map(id => arrayOfAllObjects.find(obj => obj.id == id));`. **Note:** IDs who don't have an object in the array will be mapped to `null`, so if `IDList = [125, 126, 127]` and there isn't an object with ID equal to 126, then the resulting array will be `[ { id: 125, ...}, null, { id: 127, ...} ]`